# En que se usan los registros EBP EDI ESI

Tags: ensamblador

Se que el EAX funciona como acumulador y para llamar a interrupciones

El ESP lo usan las intrucciones push y pop

Al ECX lo usan como contador para loop

Pero EBP ,EDI ,ESI no se bien como funcionan , si interactuan con una intruccion como ESP con push y pop.

Answer (score 1):

Para la arquitectura x86 - 64bits existen los siguientes registros:

**Registros Generales [GPR]**
Como el nombre lo dice, son registros de uso general. Sirven para hacer la mayoría de las operaciones comunes.

- Registro acumulador `RAX`
- Registro Base `RBX`
- Registro Contador `RCX`
- Registro Datos `RDX`

Todos estos registros permiten acceder a secciones de si mismos, para ello hay que referirse a ellos como `RAX` para los 64 bits; `EAX` para 32 bits; `AX` para los 16 primeros bits; `AH` para la segunda mitad de los 16 primeros bits; `AL` para los primeros 8 bits. Esto aplica para todos los demás registros generales (y tambien para los indices y punteros). Para entender como se distribuyen se puede ver el siguiente esquema:

`[       64 bits = 8 Bytes     RAX                            ]`
`[       32 bits = 4 Bytes      |             EAX             ]`
`[                              |              |      AX      ]`
`[                              |              |   AH  |  AL  ]`

**Indices y punteros**
Esto mantienen indice y apuntadores (direcciones de memoria).

- Registro de indice de destino [Destination index] `RDI`
- Registro de indice de origen [Source index] `RSI`
  Usados para mantener la dirección de destino y origen (respectivamente) en operaciones de copia de arreglos (vectores) y cadenas de texto.
- Registro de puntero a origen de pila [Stack Base pointer] `RBP`
  Este registro mantiene la dirección del origen de la pila.
- Registro de puntero a pila [Stack pointer] `RSP`
  Este registro mantiene la dirección al elemento mas reciente de la pila.
- Registro de puntero a instrucción `EIP`
  Este registro mantiene la dirección de la siguiente instrucción.

Al igual que en los registros generales, se puede acceder a porciones de estos registros con `RSI`, `ESI` y `SI`. (también aplica para los demás registros ej: `RDI`, `EDI`, `DI`).

Puedes ver mas información de lo registro que faltan en [X86 arquitecture.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture)